# Add connect library to PostgreSQL into Azure App Service

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, azure

I have a problem with the connection from the App Service to the PostgreSQL server. Before the application runing on MySQL, and everything worked, it was decided to move it to postrgres and then with App Service problems started. At first it was read many resources to find out how to connect the appropriate extensions PHP (direct access to the php.ini is out, so I had to do in terms of parameters AppSettings) but it did not help, and now another kind of error and how to solve it until I can not think:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\ ext \ php_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\ ext \ php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

those. Now it is necessary to connect directly to the web (presumably IIS) module works with postgresql, but how to do it? On the server, Apache is solved in connection libpq.dll library in configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure doesn't enable the extension of `php_pgsql.dll` and `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in PHP runtime. You can simply enable these extensions with following steps:

1. Add an App Setting to your Web App with the key **PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR** and value `d:\home\site\ini`
2. Create an ini file in `d:\home\site\ini` called `extensions.ini`
3. Add configuration settings to the `extensions.ini` file using the same syntax you would use in a `php.ini` file. For example:

   `extension = php_pdo_pgsql.dll
   extension = php_pgsql.dll`
4. Restart your Web App to load the changes, you can use `phpinfo()` to check the extensions.

Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime for more info.

Comment: What did you try?  And is that all the info you got in your original question?

Comment: I try all 3 methods from your link, and every take error in page "could not find driver" postgresql

Comment: You just need to follow the 4 steps in my answer. Additionally, you can modify the **PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR** to what ever folder in your root directory, e.g. `d:\home\site\wwwroot\ini`. If so, you can directly create a folder named `ini` in your root directory of your site. And create the  `d:\home\site\ini` in this folder. I used `pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=username password=password")
    or die("Can't connect to database".pg_last_error());` to test the configurations, it worked perfect on my side. Please double check the steps.